# Can we restrict to overwrite field value in document library sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, multiple-values

In Sharepoint 2013 document library from Library Setting > Advance setting and edit the template and added columns from Insert > quick part for reusability.

[image]

Now when i am creating new document. In that document that template column displays with that added columns value.but when i am changing value it overwrite that values in document.

So is there any way to keep multiple sections in document without overwrite column values.

[image]

Thanks.